# Change Namespace of an SAPUI5 Project in Web IDE

Tags: sapui5

Is there a way to change the name and namespace of an SAPUI5 project created in SAP Web IDE? I have created this SAPUI5 application using the SAPUI5 template whose name and namespace provided at the beginning of the creation needs to be changed.

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a search and replace for both forms of namespace annotation across all your files. I have done this often - typically use VS Code when doing this. 
Your 2 namespace forms typically are:

1. In your controllers:

   `sap.ui.define(['blt/ui5/controller/base/BaseController'])` being blt/ui5/
2. In your XML Views:

   < `View controllerName="blt.ui5.controller.asset.AssetList"` > being blt.ui5.